# how to make set up didn't complete untill entring specific key

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-forms-designer

I have a c# windows form and then trying to make it as set up program
I already do that but I want to make set up didn't complete until user entire valid key

For more explain :

1-I have already project its language is c# as windows form application

2- I added new project as set up project to my solution and configure it it works well but my question is

how can I add step in this setup project to enforce setup didn't complete until user enter specified key 
please help

Comment: What set up are you referring to? Could you expand on your question a bit more with examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup Project for Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243505/setup-project-for-visual-studio)

Comment: @BerndLinde ok but their is little confused , how i display the form and where  can I assign the key

Comment: Look at the last answer in that question, there is explains how to validate the key.

Comment: @BerndLinde in the form of custom action it appears my computer name by default and I would to hide it , any idea ?